# Why does String.replaceAll() need so many escapes for " character?

Tags: java, regex

If I have string `a"b"c"`, but I want to get `a\"b\"c\"`, I would naturally write

```
String t = "a\"b\"c\"";
t = t.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

However, that results in the same string, `a"b"c"`. The correct way is

```
t.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses regular expressions for both the pattern and the replacement - both of which require backslashes to be escaped. So the *regex* replacement pattern you want for the second argument is:

```
\\"
```

Now because both `\` and `"` in *Java string literals* also need escaping, that means each of those characters needs an extra backslash. Add the quotes, and you've got:

```
"\\\\\""
```

which is what you've got in your source.

It's simpler if you just use `String.replace` which *doesn't* use regular expressions. That way you're only trying to provide this string (not string literal) as the second argument:

```
\"
```

After escaping and turning into a string literal, that becomes:

```
"\\\""
```

which still isn't great, but it's at least better.

An alternative is to use `replaceAll` but with [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
t = t.replaceAll("\"", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\""));
```

Personally I'd just use `replace()` though. You don't *want* regular expression replacements, after all.

Comment: Note that according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) of `Matcher` which is used by the method, it's only "$" and "\" that need to be escaped like this

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, which is why the first string is only `\\"` instead of `\\\"`. The rest is *Java string literal* escaping.